# SceneBuilder in InteliJ Idea -> Dark Theme - Dracula

Tags: java, intellij-idea, javafx, scenebuilder

I am not sure if this belongs here, so maybe someone could show me where it belongs or simply provide we me quick support.

I am using Scene Builder in IntelliJ and I would like to have it in dark theme. I know how to set dark theme in the external SceneBuilder - but not in the Plugin.

Could someone who is using this a bit more provide me with some insight?

**Illustration:**

IntelliJ Idea:

[image]

SceneBuilder:

[image]

Would anyone maybe know how could I achieve this? :)

I am using IntelliJ Idea Community Edition.

Comment: Currently it's not possible. Please follow the related requests on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-154983, https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130580

Comment: Thank you - another thing that would also be nice is the search feature - that also is not available in the IntelliJ Idea´s SceneBuilder - at least not for me... on Windows 10 and more or less the latest IntelliJ Idea :)